# how can i save a TextField input value and provide it to another screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

im completely new to flutter and im facing some issues rn , i have a textfield which i input in some string , then i save the input through the TextEditingController , i next want to display the input in another screen , but what's happening in my case that everytime i change screens the TextEdditingcontroller.text value gets reset ,

### full code at : https://github.com/0x-xsh/studentchat/tree/master/lib

issue at https://github.com/0x-xsh/studentchat/blob/master/lib/NewProblem.dart in LINE 142 , it prints the input value in the console but sends a blank string to the new screen. so it returns an error when https://github.com/0x-xsh/studentchat/blob/master/lib/ProblemList.dart LINE 19 executes.
i tried to do a setState on Line 142 but same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `List<Problem>` parameter to our `ProblemList` class.

We can then pass in this list when navigating to our ProblemList page and access it with the following:

```
class ProblemList extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<Problem> pList;

  const ProblemList({this.pList});

  @override
  ProblemListState createState() => ProblemListState();
}

class ProblemListState extends State<ProblemList> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("My Problems"),
          leading: Icon(Icons.list),
        ),
        body: Text(widget.pList[0].desc), //<-------- This is where you access the list
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Line 142 becomes:

```
onPressed: () {
               Problem problem = new Problem(problemDescription.text, problemDetails.text);
               problems.add(problem);
               print(problems[0].desc);
               Navigator.push(context,
               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
               ProblemList(pList: problems))); //<----- Passing the list to the class
                  },
```

Comment: the strange thing is that all the other arguments (module level for example) can be passed the way i did but the TextInput just doesn't seem to work , why is that ?

Comment: @Nazim i'm unsure as to your question as (correct me if i'm wrong) i cannot find another instance of you attempting to pass state to another page. Can you please elaborate or point me to a place in your code?

Comment: i already tried it before and just deleted it , for example in line 19 at ProblemList you can just pass in the text widget : Text(appState().Selectedlevel), and it'll work , i also have another question , what's the usage of the "widget" keyword in widget.plist ? thank you so much for answering i looked it up everywhere

Comment: When your appState class gets called, you are instantiating you 'problems' list as empty (line 19) and so when you call appstate.problems in problemList, the list will still be empty as setState causes only the build method to run again and will no re-instantiate the whole appstate class. The reason selected level works is because it is instantiated with a value of 1.

The widget keyword refers to the parent widget. The parent widget of problemsList is Appstate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the state of other page like you do in `ProblemList.dart`...

You'll need to pass the list as an argument to the ProblemList. 
Try to declare a `List<Problem> problems;` inside the ProblemList class, add this variable to class constructor and send the list on `NewProblem.dart`, line 147.

Also, you code is a mess... The files have a name and the classes have another name.. Very confusing... 
Always try to use the correct naming convention to your files and classes. This will help you and whoever is trying to help you :)

https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style

When you have a better understanding of Flutter, I recommend you to learn about state management with Flutter.. There's a lot of ways. Take a look at some options and pick the one that better corresponds to your project needs...